# How to run scheduler asynchronously in C#?

Tags: c#

In my c# project I am consuming my api methods and I would like to implement scheduler which will be run every 60 minutes. After this my application will be dockerized and will run in Ubuntu server. I used [this solution](https://codinginfinite.com/creating-scheduler-task-seconds-minutes-hours-days/).

My scheduler service looks like this:

```
    public class SchedulerService
    {
        private static SchedulerService _instance;
        private List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();
        private SchedulerService() { }
        public static SchedulerService Instance => _instance ??= new SchedulerService();
        public void ScheduleTask(int hour, int min, double intervalInHour, Action task)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime firstRun = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, min, 0, 0);
            if (now > firstRun)
            {
                firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
            }
            TimeSpan timeToGo = firstRun - now;
            if (timeToGo <= TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                timeToGo = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
            var timer = new Timer(x =>
            {
                task.Invoke();
            }, null, timeToGo, TimeSpan.FromHours(intervalInHour)); 
            timers.Add(timer);
        }
    }
```

MyScheduler class which is using service:

```
    public static class MyScheduler
    {
        public static void IntervalInSeconds(int hour, int sec, double interval, Action 
     task)
        {
            interval = interval/3600;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, sec, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInMinutes(int hour, int min, double interval, Action 
         task)
        {
            interval = interval/60;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInHours(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInDays(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            interval = interval * 24;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }

    }
```

For testing I tested run in every 10 second but Scheduler not working at all. I am sure of my methods I tested without scheduler and they are working.

My Main method looks like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TAIKUN_USER") == null ||
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TAIKUN_PASSWORD") == null ||
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TAIKUN_URL") == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify all credentials");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        MyScheduler.IntervalInSeconds(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Second, 10, async () 
            =>
        {
            await PollerRequests.CreateBillingInfo(60);
            await PollerRequests.CreateBillingInfo(59);
            await PollerRequests.CreateBillingSummary(60);
            await PollerRequests.CreateBillingSummary(59);
        });
    }
```

Comment: What kind of timer are you using? Also I am filing to see where the timer is started.

Comment: How many of these "tasks" do you expect to be running?  If you are using System.Threadin.Timer.... I suggest you use a System.Timers.Timer.  There are better ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I never tried to use scheduler before, I followed tutorial which I mentioned above, for testing I used make request every 10 seconds but in final I will use only one make request every 60 minutes

Comment: Have you looked at [the timed background tasks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks)?

Comment: @StephenCleary yes but not sure it is continued task or not

Comment: @StephenCleary this link for .net core and I don't have startup class simple console app with Main method

Comment: You said you're planning to run on Ubuntu in Docker. You'll need to use .NET Core for that.

Comment: @StephenCleary of course my project in .net core but without startup file cause it is console application,created using rider in mac

Comment: Modern (3.0+) .NET Core applications use a standard startup with host builder and everything, even for console apps. I recommend you adopt that approach now since that's the future for console apps.